# In Ruby, how do I specify a file in another directory as an input?

Tags: ruby, relative-path, directory

This probably has a simple answer, but I'm working on a test suite that requires an input file that is in a different folder.  I'd like to use a relative path, like this:

```
@graph = Graph.new('../lib/test_input.txt')
```

But Ruby doesn't like that.  What's the best way to use a relative file path like that?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't like that? Maybe the current dir is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean relative to the current file, you'll probably want something like:

```
@graph = Graph.new(File.expand_path(__FILE__, "../lib/test_input.txt"))
```

If you mean relative to the current directory, you'll probably want something like:

```
@graph = Graph.new(File.expand_path(Dir.pwd, "../lib/test_input.txt"))
```

[bonus link!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path)