# RUBY: How to write a method, that accepts a file path as an argument, that loads a YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have the method:

```
`# require modules here
 require "yaml"
```

`def load_library(file_path)
     # code goes here
     file_path = YAML.load_file('emoticons.yml')
     file_path
   end`

And I am trying to get it to load the `emoticons.yml` file but when I try running the method with the file path argument

`load_library(".lib/emoticons.yml")`

I get the following error:

```
<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - emoticons.yml>
```

backtrace:

```
./lib/translator.rb:6:in load_library' 
./spec/translator_spec.rb:4:in block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' 
./spec/translator_spec.rb:4:in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' 
./spec/translator_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax or maybe I need to put the `require "yaml"` within the method?

Comment: “I get an error.” You should share that error with the people you're asking for help debugging it.

Comment: are you sure the file path is `.lib/emoticons.yml` instead of `./lib/emoticons.yml`?

Comment: @jaydel sorry that was a typo. I am using `./lib/emoticons.yml` but it still gives me the error

Comment: @coreyward here is the error:  #load_library accepts one argument, the file path
     `Failure/Error: expect { load_library("./lib/emoticons.yml") }.to_not raise_error
       expected no Exception, got #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - emoticons.yml> with backtrace:
         # ./lib/translator.rb:6:in `load_library'
         # ./spec/translator_spec.rb:4:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # ./spec/translator_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/translator_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: @M.C. It looks like your method works fine — your question/problem is “Why am I getting a ‘No such file’ error”.

Comment: @coreyward yeah I'm not sure why it's not recognizing the file. I checked my spec file and and backtracked the file path and it seems right.

Comment: This method makes no sense at all. It takes a file path as an argument, but it never uses that argument, it immediately overwrites it. If it ignores its argument anyway, then why does it take one?

Comment: my assumption, possibly wrong, is that in the current state of his code, he's trying to just hardcode the path to see what is happening there w/o worrying about how it's called. The part that confuses me is that `load_file` returns the YAML data, not a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're running into is that you're expecting the File commands to use the application root directory as the current directory (pwd), but it's using `ENV['PWD']`.

For example, if your file is at `app/helpers/yaml.rb`, your call to `Yaml.load_file` will look for the file at `app/helpers/lib/emoticons.yml`.

If the file is actually in another directory, like `your_rails_app/lib/emoticons.yml`, you can specify the directory ([In Ruby, how do I specify a file in another directory as an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432498/in-ruby-how-do-i-specify-a-file-in-another-directory-as-an-input)).

Rails also has an easier way of getting to this: `Rails.root`. This method returns a `Pathname` instance pointing to the directory of your Rails application. A convenient method on `Pathname` is [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-join), which will automatically concatenate the strings you hand it and put the necessary forward slashes in between without duplicates.

Thus, you can use this to specify the full path of your file for `Yaml.load_file`:

```
YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('lib', 'emoticons.yml'))
```

If you want to handle that in the method you can, or you can specify the full path in the argument you send to the method.

Comment: Thank you @coreyward! I decided to just set the full path to a variable and then use that as the argument

Answer (score 0):

User abosulte path instead of relative path

Instead of

`.lib/emoticons.yml`

try using

`Rails.root.join('lib', 'emoticons.yml')`

Comment: The test I'm trying to pass is using `./lib/emoticons.yml` as the argument. Should I use `Rails.root.join('lib', 'emoticons.yml')` in the method or as the argument?

Comment: Using `Rails.root` guarantees that you'll find the file using the path from the root of your Rails project. using it as a relative link can be wonky and fragile.

Comment: It is recommendable to send `Rails.root.join('lib', 'emoticons.yml')` as an argument
By doing so this method will be generic and can be used for loading any other `.yml` file by just passing the argument in the method